# Understanding Comparator call to compare method

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I am going through the following code from [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/12/examples-to-demonstrate-comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class HDTV {
    private int size;
    private String brand;

    public HDTV(int size, String brand) {
        this.size = size;
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }
}

class SizeComparator implements Comparator<HDTV> {
    @Override
    public int compare(HDTV tv1, HDTV tv2) {
        int tv1Size = tv1.getSize();
        int tv2Size = tv2.getSize();

        if (tv1Size > tv2Size) {
            return 1;
        } else if (tv1Size < tv2Size) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HDTV tv1 = new HDTV(55, "Samsung");
        HDTV tv2 = new HDTV(60, "Sony");
        HDTV tv3 = new HDTV(42, "Panasonic");

        ArrayList<HDTV> al = new ArrayList<HDTV>();
        al.add(tv1);
        al.add(tv2);
        al.add(tv3);

        Collections.sort(al, new SizeComparator());
        for (HDTV a : al) {
            System.out.println(a.getBrand());
        }
    }
}
```

When `new SizeComparator()` method is called inside `Collections.sort()`, as far as I have understood size of `tv1` is first compared to `tv2`. And here since `tv1` size is less than `tv2`,the `compare` method will return `-1`. In the next step, how will the size of `tv3` would be compared?
Is it like `-1` is compared to `42` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should -1 be compared to 42? 42 will be compared to 55 or 60 depending on the sorting algorithms used by Collections.sort.

The easiest way to check and see what is happening is to add something add some debug information, for example

```
@Override
    public int compare(HDTV tv1, HDTV tv2) {

        System.out.println("Comparing " tv1.getSize() + " to " tv2.getSize())

        int tv1Size = tv1.getSize();
        int tv2Size = tv2.getSize();

        if (tv1Size > tv2Size) {
            return 1;
        } else if (tv1Size < tv2Size) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compare is done between the objects not the values returned by the other comparison.
So then it will be tv2 compare with tv3 (return 1), tv3 with tv1 (return -1).

Answer (score 0):

Compare method does not actually sort the list. It is merely used for the comparison of two objects you provide.

`Collections.sort` method uses standard sorting algorithm and it uses your implemented `compare` method anytime it needs while sorting. Hence you can not make any assumptions about which objects will be compared.